# Kubernetes cannot join server cluster

Tags: opensuse, kubernetes

I have two OpenSUSE Micro Leap 5.5 VMs in the same network called m0.k8b.intranet.domain and m1.k8b.intranet.domain. Both are clean Preconfigured images from https://get.opensuse.org/leapmicro/5.5/.

The two virtual machines have installed containerd,  kubeadm, kubelet, but kubectl only in m0 like in https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/ and https://blog.kubesimplify.com/how-to-install-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm-containerd-and-cilium-a-hands-on-guide.

In general the https://blog.kubesimplify.com/how-to-install-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm-containerd-and-cilium-a-hands-on-guide was followed with m0 being the master and m1 being the slave, but when was time of m0 to join the m1 cluster I get the following error:

```
error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: could not find a JWS signature in the cluster-info ConfigMap for token ID "a4rvza"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cheeking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387634/the-cluster-info-configmap-does-not-yet-contain-a-jws-signature-for-token-id-cj and https://serverfault.com/questions/728727/kubernetes-stuck-on-containercreating results that in the creation of ...-controller-manager-... pod is failing because is trying to create a file at /usr/libexec which is read only by the immutable nature of the distro.